# What are some steps to trouble shoot denied HTTPS requests in IIS 7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ssl, troubleshooting

I'm hosting a site in IIS 7 that's using a wildcard certificate from RapidSSL. To date there's been no issues of people not being able to connect to the site with SSL. Now we have a client who can't connect from every machine in their network. The client machines are Red Hat and Windows XP. They can make HTTP requests ok but HTTPS return a 403.16 error. Since they aren't reaching our ASP.NET code there isn't any debug info I can get from there and nothing from IIS is being logged.

The requests are coming from both a web browser and a custom piece of software sending us notifications. Neither works.

Things checked so far:

- No errors in the Application Log
- Verified the entire certificate chain is installed and not just the client certificate

Answer (score 2):

IIS is rejecting the *client* certificate. This generally means that your server doesn't have the CA which was used to generate the *client* certificates. You will need to obtain this from the client and install it on the IIS server.

See this Microsoft KB article: [Error message when you visit a Web site that is hosted on IIS 7.0: "HTTP Error 403.16 - Forbidden"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942061)

Comment: When I view the Certification Path for the certificate IIS is using it goes GeoTrust Global CA > RapidSSL CA > Our Certificate. All 3 are installed under Computer Account and ours is under Personal, RapidSSL is under Intermediate Certification Authorities, and GeoTrust is under Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

Comment: You're still looking at the _server_ certificate. It's the _client_ certificate that is being rejected.